# How to search the folder in the google drive V3 using java?

Tags: java, google-drive-api, drive

How to search the folder in the google drive V3 using java ?

```
       String queryParam1 ="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and 
         trashed=false";

      com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.List qry =    drive.files().list().setQ(queryParam1).setCorpus("domain").setSpaces("drive");
      com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList gLst = qry.execute();
```

This code returns nothing.  I have many folders but returns zero result.
I could search the files but not a folder .

Comment: couple of things to check,  If you remove the query, do the folders appear in the response? have you checked nextPageToken to see if there are subsequent pages that you need to fetch? Do you own the folders, or have they been shared to you?

Comment: I tried all those options, still zero results. It all folder created by me and owned by me.

Answer (score 0):

In v2, [`Children: list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list) is used to list a folder's children and to list all children of the root folder, use the alias root for the folderId value.

However, it's stated in [Migrate to Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration) that `Children` and `Parents` collections have been removed. Use [`files.list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) instead.

With this, try adding `parents` property in your `q` parameter. This related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37007172/6092067) might help.

Comment: Tried exactly as suggested by you and other SO, it does not give any result back.