# Google Drive Get Files From Folder

Tags: android, kotlin, google-drive-api

How to get list of file of specific folder from google drive using drive api

Ref :: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation

#### `FileList`

```
 public  Task<FileList> fetchLatestInformation(@NotNull String backupDir) {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () -> {
            Drive.Files.List list = drive.files().list().setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name, modifiedTime, size, createdTime, parents, appProperties)");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name = '");
            sb.append(backupDir);
            sb.append("'");
            list.setQ(sb.toString());
            list.setPageSize(1000);
            list.setOrderBy("modifiedTime");
            return list.execute();
        });
    }
```

#### `ActivityCode`

```
    googleDrive.fetchLatestInformation(backupDir)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                var files = it.files
                files.reverse()
                files.forEach {
                    Log.e(TAG,"file :: ${it?.name}")
                }
                var file = files.firstOrNull()

                if (file != null) {
                    var time = file.modifiedTime
                    var date = Date(time.value)
                    var simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm aaa")
                    Log.e(TAG,"lastBackup name :: ${file.name}")
                    Log.e(TAG,"lastBackup date :: ${simpleDateFormat.format(date)}")
                    Log.e(TAG,"lastBackup size :: ${file.getSize()?.formatFileSize}")

                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                it.printStackTrace()
            }
```

#### `LogResult`

```
E/BackupActivity: file :: AppBackup
E/BackupActivity: lastBackup name :: AppBackup
E/BackupActivity: lastBackup date :: Tue, 19 May 2020 10:44 PM
    lastBackup size :: null
```

but `AppBackup` is directory which contains the backup files zips so my question is how to get a files which is stored in `AppBackup` Directory.

NOTE :: [I AM USING DRIVE API V3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public  Task<FileList> fetchLatestInformation(@NotNull String parentFolderId) {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () -> {

            Drive.Files.List list = drive.files().list().setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name, modifiedTime, size, createdTime, parents, appProperties)");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("'");
            sb.append(parentFolderId);
            sb.append("'");
            sb.append(" in parents and mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false");
            list.setQ(sb.toString());
            list.setPageSize(1000);
            list.setOrderBy("modifiedTime");
            return list.execute();
        });
    }
```

`Children.List` was removed in V3 so we want to use list() we can query using `'parentFolderId' in parents and mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false`

In v2, [`Children: list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list) is used to list a folder's children and to list all children of the root folder, use the alias root for the folderId value.

However, it's stated in [Migrate to Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration) that `Children` and `Parents` collections have been removed. Use [`files.list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) instead.

Ref : [How to search the folder in the google drive V3 using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292203/how-to-search-the-folder-in-the-google-drive-v3-using-java/45329820#45329820)

Answer (score 1):

Use HTTP request
`GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/folderId/children` to get children of folder using folder Id

```
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Children;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.ChildList;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.ChildReference;

import java.io.IOException;

// ...

public class MyClass {

  // ...

  /**
   * Print files belonging to a folder.
   *
   * @param service Drive API service instance.
   * @param folderId ID of the folder to print files from.
   */
  private static void printFilesInFolder(Drive service, String folderId)
      throws IOException {
    Children.List request = service.children().list(folderId);

    do {
      try {
        ChildList children = request.execute();

        for (ChildReference child : children.getItems()) {
          System.out.println("File Id: " + child.getId());
        }
        request.setPageToken(children.getNextPageToken());
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        request.setPageToken(null);
      }
    } while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
             request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
  }

  // ...

}
```

For more [check](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/children/list#request)

Comment: ohk i am using v3 api so i need to switch?

Comment: you didn't mention what API you are using. So I suggested you with an answer. you just need to change the path v2->v3

Comment: ohk but Children.List not found in v3

Comment: I didn't use v3 before so, I can't say anything about it check this https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_google_document

Comment: i know i am also stucked never used drive api before they removed children() in v3

Comment: Great to hear that I'm able to help you 